# Windows 7 screen went blank after dual boot with ubuntu

Tags: windows, xubuntu, windows-7, error-handling, selinux

This is how my screen appears while clicking on windows 7. Recently I dual booted Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 but after the process Ubuntu works properly but the screen goes blank while opening Windows 7. What am I supposed to do??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Not a Grub or Ubuntu problem**

You're having a problem with Windows.  This isn't an Ubuntu issue.  Windows is supported under the Grub boot manager.  After the boot process is passed to the Windows loader, it's all up to the integrity of Windows to finish complete the load process.  If there is a problem with Windows, it won't load no matter which Boot manager has initiated.

It's a coincident that you are dual booting Ubuntu and see a problem with Windows, not a cause.  I can understand how apparent it might seem that Ubuntu or Grub has something to do with the problem, but that's not it.

**Fix Windows**

The answer is to fix windows.  You can only do that on the Windows side with Windows tools such as Booting to a Windows disk and running the available routines to fix it.

**Reinstall Grub**

In the process of repairing Windows, the Windows install disk will most likely replace the Grub boot Manager with Windows boot manager.  You won't be able to run Ubuntu from the Windows boot manager, so after that you will have to reinstall Grub, which supports booting into either Linux or Windows.

For this part, look at [RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

**You can get more detailed help with fixing the windows problem** in one of the forums such as http://superuser.com.